# Can a plugin a developed without using Maven?

Tags: sonarqube

We would like to start developing custom/internal SonarQube plugins (rules) in our organization but we can't get our hands on Apache Maven at the moment. All development tools must go through a rigorous certification process.

Ant being the current build tool of choice in our organization, is it possible to create a new SonarQube plugin (not being published to the marketplace) by replicating the same standard structure that is expected from SonarQube?

I've already read the [following post](http://sonarqube-archive.15.x6.nabble.com/Creating-plugin-without-Maven-td5025411.html) from the SonarQube archives, but was wondering if that would still be possible to do with a little bit of elbow grease?

Concerning the answer from Simon Brandhof, I think that the plugin key, manifest generation and mandatory properties could easily be generated from well crafted Ant build script, as long as putting all required JARs in the classpath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far I know for developping new rules It is mandatory to create a new Sonarqube plugin and can be only build with the maven way.

see https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/DEV/Build+Plugin